# UK cladding remediation

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, lease

In the old format of the [Leaseholder certificate](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/mandatory-information-required-from-leaseholders-and-building-owners#full-publication-update-history),

Does landlord not being responsible for the defect, having net worth of >2MN, yet the maximum liability for relevant historical safety defects for this lease where the landlord is not connected to the developer being £0 imply that the lease is a qualifying lease?

Why is the phrase "landlord is not connected to the developer" used here?